# Ubuntu Server SVN over SSH not working

Tags: server, ssh, svn

I am trying to checkout a repository on my computer using:

```
svn co svn+ssh://name@ipaddress/usr/local/svn/repos/testing
```

And I get an error saying this:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://name@ipaddress/usr/local/svn/repos/testing'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

The thing is, ssh is working I can SSH in the machine. I can also checkout the repository using the same command while logged into the server machine.

Does anybody know what could be wrong? Do I need to be logged into SSH first, and then try to check it out? If so how do I checkout to the Desktop of the machine im working on?

Bit of a linux noob, help would be appreciated

Comment: did you "To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file." ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Is that the svnserve.conf file? If so, there is no [tunnels] section

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644791/network-connection-closed-unexpectedly-upon-svn-checkout